# The negation of statements

Tags: logic

> Write the negation of each of the following statements
>
> 1. One quarter of the people who entered the competition won a prize.
> 2. At least two of the above statements are false

My attempt:

1. One quarter of the people who entered the competition did not win a prize
2. At least two of the above statements are true

Are these answers correct ? If not what are the right answers ?

Comment: The second one is not correct (suppose there are four statements, two true and two false).  For the first, I think it depends on exactly what is meant.   That is, do they mean $\textit {exactly}$ a quarter or $\textit {at least}$ a quarter.  Though with either interpretation, your negation is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

For 1) I interpret the original statement to be saying that exactly one quarter of the people who entered the competition won a prize.

1 - An amount different than one quarter of the people who entered the competition won a prize

2 - Less than two of the above statements are false

This is effectively saying that the negation of $x=0.25$ is the statement $x\neq 0.25$ while the negation of the statement $y\geq 2$ is the statement $y<2$

Answer (score 2):

Your anwers are not correct:

1) what if half of all people win a prize?  Then both statements for 1 are false, meaning they are not each other's negation

2) what if there are two statements, one true and one false?  Then both statemwnts for 2 are false, and hence again they are not the negation of each other.

Do you see how to correct for this?